# Pivotal tracker git integration not working for pull requests

Tags: github, pivotaltracker

Is there any way to add a comment to a story in Pivotal tracker when a git pull request is done. Pivitoltracker + Git integration works only for push.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should go to Programmers

Comment: @iDevlop this question is not a good fit for Programmers currently. It's more of a question for Pivotal support, though my understanding is some git questions are on topic here on Stack Overflow.